# How to allow Dropbox to auto-update by adding an exception to ESET firewall?

Tags: firewall, dropbox, rules, automatic-update, eset

I am using ESET Smart Security v5.2.9.1 and Dropbox at Windows 7 x64.

The problem that I am facing is that every time Dropbox wants to auto-update, it downloads an updater file that has different filename each time, containing the version number, prohibiting me from creating an exception for it, to allow it freely update itself, without user interaction.

Is there a way to make ESET to allow the update process done automatically each time without popping up any alerts?

Comment: Can't you exclude the folder the updater runs from, or perhaps the folder it's trying to update files in?

Comment: I've tried to create a rule for the entire folder to no avail. Also tried using wildcard to match the filename pattern, but didn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a rule for Dropbox:
Go to NOD32 -> setup -> network -> Configure Rules and Zones ->New
Then pick a name for the rule and go to the 'Local' Tab, press Browse and browse to dropbox location, choose the .exe and apply the rule.
Now edit the rule to allow all requests.

Comment: As I say at the question, the filename is changed each time a new update is found.